# Derivative using Numpy or Other Library for lambda sin function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, derivative

So i have this newton optimation problem where i must found the value f'(x) and f''(x) where x = 2.5 and the f = 2 * sin(x) - ((x)**2/10) for calculating, but i tried using sympy and np.diff for the First and Second Derivative but no clue, cause it keep getting error so i go back using manual derivate, Any clue how to derivative the function f with help of other library, Here's the code

```
def Newton(x0):
  x = x0
  f = lambda x : 2 * np.sin (x) - ((x)**2/10)
  f_x0 = f(x0)
  #First Derivative
  f1 = lambda x : 2 * np.cos (x) - ((x)/5)
  f_x1 = f1(x0)
  #Second Derivative
  f2 = lambda x : -2 * np.sin (x) - (1/5)
  f_x2 = f2(x0)


  x1 = x0 - (f_x1/f_x2)
  x0 = x1

  return x,f_x0,f_x1,f_x2,x0
```

finding first and second derivative without the manual way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the derivates can be calculated using the scipy library as follows:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def f(x):
    return 2 * sin(x) - ((x)**2/10)

print("First derivative:" , derivative(f, 2.5, dx=1e-9))
print("Second derivative", derivative(f, 2.5, n=2, dx=0.02))
```

Here the first and second derivative is calculated for your function at x=2.5.

The same can be done with the sympy library and some may find this easier than the above method.

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
y = 2 * sin(x) - ((x)**2/10) #function
yprime = y.diff(x) #first derivative function
ydoubleprime = y.diff(x,2) #second derivative function

f_first_derivative = lambdify(x, yprime)
f_second_derivative = lambdify(x, ydoubleprime)

print("First derivative:" , f_first_derivative(2.5))
print("Second derivative",f_second_derivative(2.5))
```

Comment: Note that there are not just 2 methods to do the same thing. The first one is a numeric estimation of the derivatives. While the second is a symbolic exact computation. The second won't work for any functions (sometimes, even humans don't know how to compute derivative other than numerically). The first always works (as long as we can compute `y` for any value of `x`), but always has an error.